# React SwiperJs autoplay not making the swiper to auto swipe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I am using this swiper in React:
https://swiperjs.com/react/

I tried to make it "autoplay" but it doesn't auto swipe.
This is what I tried:

```
// https://swiperjs.com/get-started/
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    SwiperStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
        height: '58px',
        width: '100%',
    },
});

export default function TextInfoSlider(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>

            <Swiper
                loop={true}
                autoplay={{
                    delay: 500,
                    disableOnInteraction: false
                }}
            >

                <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>

            </Swiper>

            <style jsx global>{`
                    .swiper-container {
                        background-color: #f5f5f5;
                    }
           `}</style>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have also tried to just use boolean on the autoplay but it also doesn't work:

```
        <Swiper
            loop={true}
            autoplay={true}
            }}
        >
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`By default Swiper React uses core version of Swiper (without any additional components). If you want to use Navitation, Pagination and other components, you have to install them first`

It does not seem you have installed `Autoplay` component.

```js
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay } from 'swiper';
...
SwiperCore.use([Autoplay]);
```

Comment: Can you specify how to use delay?

Comment: THis does not fix the issue - however this is correct in terms of this is needed

Answer (score 23):

https://swiperjs.com/demos#autoplay

import modules from swiper and pass it as props to Swiper component

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper";

   <Swiper
        spaceBetween={30}
        centeredSlides={true}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 2500,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        navigation={true}
        modules={[Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 12):

configur swiper in `App.js`or wherever you like:

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay } from 'swiper';

function App() {

  SwiperCore.use([Autoplay])

  ...
}
```

then use like this:

`<Swiper autoplay={{ delay: 3000 }} >...</Swiper>`

Answer (score 7):

in NextJs run for me with this code:

```
import {  Pagination } from 'swiper';
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/autoplay';

// ...
const HomeComponent = () => {
  SwiperCore.use([Autoplay]);
return (
    <Swiper
          className="home_slider"
          modules={[Pagination,Autoplay]}
          slidesPerView={1}
          onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
          onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
          pagination={{ clickable: true }}
          autoplay
        >
          <SwiperSlide>
           <Image src={Image1}  alt='' />
          </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
)
```

Comment: Now I just need to get my buttons with onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()} and onClick={() => swiper.slidePrev()} to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

for swiper version 8.3

imports should look like this

```
import { Autoplay, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/autoplay";
```

and your swiper react component, mine wasnt working on `autoplay={true}` so I added `autoplay={{delay: 2000}` anyways below is my whole swiper it will help you

```
<Swiper
    modules={[Autoplay, Pagination]}
    pagination={{clickable: true}}
    slidesPerView={1}
    autoplay={{
          delay: 2000,
          pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
          disableOnInteraction: false
         }}
    loop
    className='swiper-container'
 >
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to import

```
import { Autoplay, Pagination } from "swiper";
```

then in Swiper Component

```
 <Swiper
    slidesPerView={1}
    loop={true}
    pagination={{ clickable: true}}
    modules={[Pagination,Autoplay]}
    className={`mySwiper ${styledClasses}`}
    autoplay={{ delay: 2000}}
  > 
  {/* Slider here */}
  </Swiper
```

this will run it properly in reactjs

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error but after trying the different tricks provided here noting worked so i lastly i tried:

To solve this problem i had to directly search for the Autoplay component in the swiper doc found inside the node_modules as follows.

**import Autoplay from './../../../node_modules/swiper/modules/autoplay.mjs';**

Answer (score 0):

if none of mentioned solutions worked, just give swiper component a key

```
<Slider01.Slider
          items={sliderItems}
          slidesPerView={sliderItems?.length > 1 ? 1.2 : 1}
          spaceBetween={20}
          radius={12}
          modules={[Navigation, Autoplay]}
          navigation
          key={sliderItems.length}
          loop
          autoplay={{
            delay: 1500,
            disableOnInteraction: false
          }}
```